Selenium issues with stale element reference @Python
I am writing to you after having done a little bit on research on this error "Stale element reference" and unfortunately, I still have not being able how to treat this issue.
I am using Selenium for scraping all the ticket symbols in the nasdaq website for all the pages displayed.
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}

#Example
url_test = "https://www.fdic.gov/resources/resolutions/bank-failures/failed-bank-list"
# NYSE
url_nyse = "http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&exchange=nyse&render=download"
# Nasdaq
url_nasdaq = "http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&exchange=nasdaq&render=download"
# AMEX
url_amex = "http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&exchange=amex&render=download"

#We acess to the website of NYSE
driver.get(url_nyse)
#We accept the privacy policy conditions banner. It appears only at the beginning
driver.find_element(By.ID,"onetrust-accept-btn-handler").click()

#We get the maximum number of pages in the website
#total_pages = soup.find_all("button",class_="pagination__page")
#end = total_pages[-1].text

#We do a loop to store all the stocks of each page in the NYSE website. Currently, we are testing with just 10 pages
for i in range(1,10):
    try:
        # We get the html source from the website
        html = driver.page_source

        # Now, we call our friend BeautifulSoup and parse all the html code
        soup = bs(html, "html.parser")

        #We look for all the <th> tags in the class ="nasdaq-screener__cell" to get the Symbols of each stock
        Symbols = soup.find_all("th",class_="nasdaq-screener__cell")

        for each in Symbols:
            stocks = each.text
            print(stocks)

        #We add a counter to select the next page number
        np = i+1
        print("The value of np = " +str(np))

        #We retrieve the button with the next page number
        page_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"//button[@class='pagination__page' and text()='{np}']")
        print("This is the number of the page selected " + str(page_button.text))

        #We select the next page number button
        page_button.click()
        print("I have clicked on the page number #"+str(np))


    except Exception as e:
        print("This is the value of the error " +str(e))
        continue

Currently, I am having 2 issues in particular:

When I am executing the code I managed to extract the symbols for the 1st page (np=1) correctly. However, I see in the console that when I am in the 2nd page (np=2), I got the same symbols from the 1st page and once I am inside the 3rd page of NYSE, I got the tickers of the 2nd page. The pattern goes like this (page 1 & page 2 = same symbols; page 3 & page 4 = same symbols)

In my code, I purposely did not utilise the function driver.refresh(), because the URL of the page is always the same despite of the number of the page chosen and there is no URL/href attached to the html code of the buttons. Therefore, I have to retrieve the button with the number of the next page and then click the button.

Just before executing the line page_button.click(), I always got the error of stale element reference (It could happen on the 3rd, 4th or 5th page. It is aleatory). I just managed to create an exception to continue to run my code and I have found some information that explains this issue (https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/#stale-element-reference-exception), but I do not know how to correct/change the context.

I am not very experienced developper, so I thank everyone who might have an idea or experience in this subject. I would really appreciate it!
Here below the results shown in my console with the previous 2 issues that I mention above:
Pages not charged
C:\Users\chava\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe C:\Users\chava\Documents\PycharmProjects\TradingView\Test.py 
MSFT
AAPL
NVDA
GOOG
GOOGL
AMZN
META
BRK/A
BRK/B
TSM
LLY
AVGO
NVO
TSLA
JPM
WMT
V
UNH
XOM
MA
ASML
PG
ORCL
COST
JNJ
The value of np = 2
This is the number of the page selected 2
I have clicked on the page number #2
MSFT
AAPL
NVDA
GOOG
GOOGL
AMZN
META
BRK/A
BRK/B
TSM
LLY
AVGO
NVO
TSLA
JPM
WMT
V
UNH
XOM
MA
ASML
PG
ORCL
COST
JNJ
The value of np = 3
This is the number of the page selected 3
This is the value of the error Message: stale element reference: stale element not found in the current frame
  (Session info: chrome=126.0.6478.62); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#stale-element-reference-exception
Stacktrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6B31B3E52+31618]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B312B0B9]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B2FE888A]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B2FEE6BE]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B2FF1011]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B2FF10B0]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B3040119]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B303DBE2]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B303B07B]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B303A246]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B302C281]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B305D10A]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B302BBA6]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B305D320]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B307CA80]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B305CEB3]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B302A46B]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B302B001]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6B34BA02D+3202397]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6B3506A4D+3516285]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6B34FC4C0+3473904]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6B3265D56+760454]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B3136B5F]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B3131CF4]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B3131E82]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6B312122F]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFF66E6257D+29]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFF685AAA48+40]

HD
MRK
BAC
ABBV
NFLX
CVX
TM
KO
AMD
AZN
QCOM
ADBE
CCZ
PEP
CRM
SHEL
SAP
TMO
NVS
LIN
TMUS
PDD
WFC
AMAT
FMX
The value of np = 4
This is the number of the page selected 4
I have clicked on the page number #4
HD
MRK
BAC
ABBV
NFLX
CVX
TM ...


I'm not 100% sure what the issue is... but you could try ditching the counter and instead using the right arrow button to get to each next page-- driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='pagination__next']").click()

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.

(1) maybe page needs more time to load new data and you have to sleep some time.

(2) problem with click() may also needs sleep - probably you get content of old page with reference to button on previous page, meanwhile it replaces old elements with new elements, and next you try to click button which don't exist any more because it was on previous page - and this gives error Stale element reference"

some solution can be using  Waits in Selenium to search some unique element on page (like page number, or parameters in button to next page) before html = driver.page_source

it seem you can download CSV: driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(), 'Download CSV')]").click() - it gives me file with ~7000 rows.

It seems you don't have to scrape it because there is button with Download CVS
and this works for me
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(), 'Download CSV')]").click()

and you have to do it only once - so you don't have to go to next pages.

As for main problem.
It seems Selenium works faster then JavaScript which replaces data on page.
Selenium gets old page before JavaScript can remove it from memory and put new data - and you get the same values for next pages. And probably you get button from previous page.
But meanwhile JavaScript can replace data on page (in browser memory) and Selenium tries to click button which was removed from memory and this gives problem Stale element reference.
You may need to use Waits to wait for some unique element on next page - e.g. blue button with next page number. And when this button exists then browser has new data on page (and in memory) and you should get correct data and click correct button to load new page.
You may need to check active button (blue button) in pagination
f"//button[@class='pagination__page pagination__page--active' and text()='{i}']"


Full working code:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
#from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.maximize_window()

# NYSE
url = "http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&exchange=nyse&render=download"

driver.get(url)

# We accept the privacy policy conditions banner. It appears only at the beginning
driver.find_element(By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler").click()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)  # 

downloaded = False   # download only once

# We do a loop to store all the stocks of each page in the NYSE website. Currently, we are testing with just 10 pages
#while True:  # use `break` (to exit loop) when `next_button` will raise exception. 
for index in range(1, 10):
    print(f'Loading .... {index}')
    try:    
        # @class='pagination__page pagination__page--active' @data-page='{index}'
        xpath = f"//button[@class='pagination__page pagination__page--active' and text()='{index}']"
        active_button =  wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
        print('active_button:', active_button.text)

        if not downloaded:
            print('Downloadind ....')
            download = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(), 'Download CSV')]")  # text on button may have spaces and new lines
            #download.click()  # problem when button is not visible
            driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()', download)
            downloaded = True

        # get data with BeautifulSoup
        html = driver.page_source
        soup = bs(html, "html.parser")
        symbols = soup.find_all("th", class_="nasdaq-screener__cell")  # PEP8: `lower_canse_names` for variables
        for item in symbols:
            print('soup:', item.text)

        # the same without BeautifulSoup
        symbols = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//th[@class="nasdaq-screener__cell"]')  # PEP8: `lower_canse_names` for variables
        for item in symbols:
            print('selenium:', item.text)

        print('Next Page:', index+1)

        # button with the next page number
        #page_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"//button[@class='pagination__page' and text()='{index+1}']")
        #page_button.click()

        # button with arrow to the next page - 
        next_page_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='pagination__next']")
        #next_page_button.click()  # problem when button is not visible 
        driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()', next_page_button)

    except Exception as ex:
        print(f"Exception: {ex}")

input('Press ENTER to exit')
driver.close()

